# Ontario HST rebate: Is eligibility based on gross or net income?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

Is the HST rebate eligibility - of up to $166,000 combined income per couple - based on gross income or net income?

Answer (score 1):

The [Ontario Ministry of Revenue](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca) has posted a Frequently Asked Question which addresses yours exactly:  [Is the OSTTB calculated on gross or net income?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_calculation.html#Q10)  Quote:

> The OSTTB is calculated based on the
>   **adjusted family net income of the
>   recipient.** Adjusted family net income
>   is the sum of your net income (line
>   236 on your income tax return) and
>   your spouse's or common-law partner's
>   net income with certain adjustments.
>   Adjusted family net income is the
>   definition of income most commonly
>   used to assess eligibility for
>   benefits delivered through the tax
>   system.  *[emphasis mine]*